# Why I cannot move the links in my favorites folder

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks

```html
    <!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<p>
<DT><H3> LightGBM </H3>
<DL>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/102dc5fd7b5d2bae80cdf35c22d389952c10c631/docs/Parameters.md">1</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/102dc5fd7b5d2bae80cdf35c22d389952c10c631/docs/Python-API.md">2</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Python-API.md#common-methods">3</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/simple_example.py">4</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/regression/train.conf">5</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Features">6</A>
</DL>
</p>
```

This is my bookmark.html file's content, I can import this file into my IE's favorites, the problem is I cannot copy/move/delete the links as normal links created manually in IE.

If I copy one link, then the system will delete all links in one folder and copy an empty folder with the same name.

How can I solve the problem?

import into favorites folder
[image: imported into favorites folder]
after move or copy manipulation of one link
[image]
two folders, one is empty, there is one link in another.
The IE auto generate two folders after move/copy manipulation.
[image]

Comment: Use the Favorites Explorer to manage your favorites folders' .url files... type shell:favorites in the address bar of IE. Make sure the permissions on the favorites/subfolders are what you expect. Ensure you have run the latest windows updates.

Comment: @RobParsons the problem is , in the same enviroment, some htmls like this can be import and copy/move the .urls well, but some htmls can't work properly.

Comment: that's why you use the Favorites Explorer to manage your Favorites/IE Bookmarks....How did you get two LightGBM folders under the Favorites root? expected LightGBM and LightGBM(1). To deploy Favorites(.url) files on a domain network use a .ins (windows installer) file to create the .url files in the target Favorites sub folder or the Profile Editor of IEAK.

Comment: @RobParsons The windows/IE auto generate two folders, that's why I ask this question, it's weired.